Critical points of the squared distance function on surfaces
Let S be a surface, $p_0 \in \mathbb{R}^3$, we define the squared distance function $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f(p)= \| p - p_0\|^2 , p \in S$$
prove that $p_0$ is a critical point of $f$ and compute the Hessian of $f$ at $p_0$

What’s the domain of $f$? It looks like it should be $S$, but there’s no indication that $p_0\in S$, so I don’t think the problem makes sense.

This makes no sense. For the statement to make sense, $p_0$ must be a point of $S$, but then $f$ is not even differentiable at $p_0$.

$p_0 \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and $p \in S$

I'm sorry, there was a typo in the original document and I worked on an exercise that was poorly posed. I will update the question.
